# How do you troubleshoot AspNet Core missing dependencies?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

So I made a change to my project.json which caused a re-restore which is coming up with a bunch of unresolvable dependencies. How do you figure out what is going on here?  This was definitely working as I wrote quite  a bit of code against this project.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
    "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-*",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-rc2-301150021",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-15958",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-15958",
    "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-rc2-*",
    "EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-*"
  }



 NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles/index.json 514ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore/index.json 498ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions/index.json 1743ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication/index.json 1745ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.embedded/index.json 1791ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.composite/index.json 1859ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity/index.json 1892ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors/index.json 1901ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc/index.json 1875ms
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting/index.json 1887ms

NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/openiddict/index.json 1720ms
```

Comment: If you need help with the .NET CLI/ASP.NET Core migration, don't hesitate to join us on https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/AspNetCore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenIddict and all the `aspnet-contrib` projects [have been updated to use .NET CLI and the new ASP.NET Core 1.0 packages](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/pull/60), so if you restored your project recently, you're likely using the latest nightly builds, that require the new ASP.NET and aspnet-contrib packages.

To migrate, [install the .NET Core tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download).

You'll also need to update your references to use the ASP.NET Core RC2 packages. Here's an example of [an updated `project.json`](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/project.json):

```
"dependencies": {
  "AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub": "1.0.0-alpha4-final",
  "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection": "1.0.0-alpha1-final",
  "AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation": "1.0.0-alpha1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-*"
},

"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"
    }
  },

  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "type": "platform", "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702" }
    },

    "imports": [
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net451+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Don't forget to also replace the usings and [to use the new `WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Server/Startup.cs):

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
            .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
            .UseConfiguration(configuration)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hehe, that's the price to pay for using pre-release software. It would help if you shared one or two messages ;)

Comment: have you been able to get an aspnet core app running via `dotnet` command  (ie not using dnx) - i've been trying for a day now :/

Comment: Updated to use the final ASP.NET Core RC2 packages.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost - don't mix package versions. Use all rc1 or all rc2 etc. Also don't mix "old" (.AspNet. - rc1 or older) packages with new (.AspNetCore. - rc2 - not released yet) packages. If you decide to use rc2 switch to dotnet from dnx. As pointed by @Pinpoint's answer for now you need to use the aspnetcidev feed. You can find some examples of ASP.Net Core applications running on dotnet in [this repo](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples)

Comment: Not sure who downvoted your answer but +1 for giving an excellent advice: never mix old and new packages.