# IServiceProvider rc2-20215 must reference System.ComponentModel 4.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, aspnet-contrib

I thought i would upgrade my dnvm (wish i never did now), and the latest version is now rc2-20215.  Few things changed which i have managed to fix, but one thing that seems to be a bug or maybe i am missing something, is that IServiceProvider now requires a reference to System.ComponentModel 4.0.1?  Why?

Now if i add this to my project.json file, it still shows the error.

If i add it as a frameworkAssembly, i am unable to get version 4.0.1, only version 4.0.0.

Here is my nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="AspNetCiDev" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="aspnet-contrib" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="XUnit" value="https://www.myget.org/F/xunit/api/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

As you can see my global.json file is like this

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-rc2-20215",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "architecture": "x64"
    }
}
```

Here is the error message to start with

[image]

Tried adding this to project.json file, but same error as above still remains

```
"System.ComponentModel": "4.0.1-rc2-*"
```

Here you can see it cant find version 4.0.1.0 when i add it to frameworkAssembly

[image]

Anyone else come across this issue yet?  I know, you get these problems with "pre-release" software :)

Comment: How did you get `rc2-20215`? When we run `dnvm upgrade -u` the most recent we retrieve is `1.0.0-rc2-16595`. What feed are you using?

Comment: If you *really* want to be using the more recent, in my opinion it is worth using the `dotnet` driver instead of `dnvm`.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin i already have my feeds above, i believe the AspNetCiDev is the one you need, i also have overriden my unstable build to point to this to

Comment: Follow this link to update your unstable repo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518616/how-do-you-troubleshoot-aspnet-core-missing-dependencies/35519150#35519150

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable [FusionLog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to get more information about libraries references. It is quite usefull tool for such issues.